# When is "storage almost full" triggered on IOS

Tags: ios

I have an app which uses a lot of the sandbox cache temporarily. I would like to prevent the OS from triggering the "storage almost full" warning by not filling up the disk beyond the trigger point.

I cannot find documentation on how this level is set.

Is it configurable for the user ? Is it unique to the device or IOS version ?

[image]

Comment: I am using the cache to hold files while uploading and delete them once uploaded. So no need for it to be kept.

Comment: Indeed this is a real iOS warning, contrary to the two current answers, and I would also like to know an answer to this question, particularly at what level does this dialog get triggered?

Comment: Also asked [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/168465/220548) with no answers.

Answer (score -2):

**Update:**

There is a solution available for this in [Apple Developer Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6798365).

> log out of itunes store in settings, wait 10 minutes, then log back
>   in.  your storage should go back to what it should have been all
>   along.  there is an itunes media caching bug / storage leak in ios 8
>   (all versions so far)

**Original answer:**

As far as I know there is no warning like that in iOS.

You can use as much as space available in the device, there is no limitation for that. Also those cache files are temporary, it'll be automatically cleaned.

Comment: My tester definitely confirms there is a popup alert.

Comment: @RyanHeitner: are you sure that, that alert was not coming from inside your app, also can you post an image of that alert ?

Comment: Yes I am sure please see the screenshots

Comment: Thank you for the repply everything you say is valid and useful except that besides the fact that the alert does not exist

Comment: @RyanHeitner: Where are you uploading those data ? To iCloud ? If yes, then the message is for iCloud space

Comment: No not to iCloud, to my own private storage